# Show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n}{2^{n^2}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n}{2^{n^2}}$ converges absolutely. I tried using the Limit Ratio Test for Series with: $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{2^{2n+1}n^n}$$ However, I can't see how to evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\lvert$ and show that it is less than $1$. Is there a better way to show this, or should I continue down this route? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is there a better way to show this?*

The root test gives, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{n}{2^{n}}\to 0.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{2^{2n+1}n^n}=\frac{n+1}{2^{2n+1}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Since $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to e$, you just need the limit of $\frac{n+1}{2^{2n+1}}$.

Comment: It also works with the loose bound $1+1/n\le2$.

Comment: Ah, that's true, you don't actually need to know that $(1+1/n)^n\to e$.

Answer (score 1):

Try for your ratio something like $$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{2^{2n+1}n^n}=\dfrac{(n+1) \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{2^{2n+1}} \lt \dfrac{(n+1)e}{2^{2n+1}}\lt \dfrac{2^{n+1}e}{2^{2n+1}} = \dfrac{e}{2^n}$$